# Powershell nested json to repeating csv

Tags: json, powershell, csv

Kind of similar to [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829754/convert-nested-json-array-into-separate-columns-in-csv-file) but instead of flattened csv (ie discipline_01, discicpline_01) exporting to multiple lines of the csv:

```
{
"data": [{
    "attributes": {
        "id": 10011,
        "title": "Test procedure",
        "slug": "slug",
        "url": "http://test.test",
        "disciplines": [
            "discipline_a",
            "discipline_b",
            "discipline_c"
        ]
    }
}]
}
```

export to

```
"id","title","slug","url","discipline"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_a"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_b"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_c"
```

Thanks to [Export fields with nested values from JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938904/export-fields-with-nested-values-from-json-to-csv) I've gotten this far:

```
$foo = invoke-restmethod $restquery -headers $headers
$foo | 
select -ExpandProperty data | 
select -ExpandProperty attributes |
select id, title, slug, url, disciplines | 
   foreach { 
        $_.disciplines = $_disciplines -join ' ' 
        $_ | 
export-csv c:\outfile.csv -notypeinformation
```

This gives me

```
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_a discipline_b discipline_c"
```

But no clue how to get it to:

```
"id","title","slug","url","discipline"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_a"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_b"
"10011","Test procedure","slug","http://test.test","discipline_c"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your posted Json is invalid,
this might do:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\31\SO_56401395.ps1
$foo = invoke-restmethod $restquery -headers $headers

$Data = $foo.data.attributes | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($discipline in $_.disciplines}(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            id         = $_.id
            title      = $_.title
            slug       = $_.slug
            url        = $_.url
            discipline = $discipline
        }
    }
}
$Data | Export-Csv c:\outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: That did it! And learned a lot!  I also edited my json in original question to be valid.  Thanks!